# Oracle SQL show records WHERE there are more than one record for each pair of (a,b)

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am using Python to access an Oracle Exadata database, which is HUGE. The documentation for the table is rather poor and I need to understand strange cases. Coming from an R/python world I ran the following query:

```
query = ("""
         SELECT COUNT(counter) as freq, counter
         FROM (
             SELECT COUNT(*) as counter
             FROM schema.table
             WHERE x = 1 AND y = 1
             GROUP BY a,b ) 
         GROUP BY counter""")

 with cx_Oralce.connct(dsn=tsn, encoding = "UTF-8") as con:
     df = pd.read_sql(con=con, query=sql)
```

This essentially counts the frequency of observations for a given (a,b) pair. My prior was that they are all 1 (they are not). So I would like to see the observations that drive this:

```
 query = ("""
         SELECT *
         FROM schema.table
         WHERE x = 1 and y = 1
         AND (for each (a,b) there is more than one record)""")
```

I am struggling to translate this into proper Oracle SQL.

In R (`dplyr`) this would be a combination of `group_by` and `mutate` (instead of `summarise`) and in Python `pandas` this could be done with `transform`.

I am new to SQL and may use incorrect terminology. I appreciate being corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT ab.* 
FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b) as cnt
      FROM schema.table t
      WHERE x = 1 AND y = 1
     ) ab
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: I get an error: `"T": invalid identifier`, does it need to be `FROM schema.table t`?